# How can I set up dual-boot with Windows on my SSD and Ubuntu on my HDD?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

So on my windows computer I currently have this set up for my partitions, I shrunk down the D:/ drive to make 100gb were I would like to install Ubuntu and dual boot it with windows on which is found in the C:/ drive

Below is an image of my partitions from windows:

[Partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaW7B.png)

When I boot into the Ubuntu disk, do I chose the first option still to install it alongside windows boot manager? as seen in this tutorial below:

http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside.html

or is there a different procedure i should follow since they're 2 different drives?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is sdb partitioned with gpt(GUID) or MBR(msdos)? If you are using UEFI be sure to use gpt. Only one ESP - efi system partition per device. But grub does default to install to ESP on sda, not sdb's ESP.  That is ok if internal drive, if external we have to manually copy files to external drive's ESP.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply.... it is a gpt partition and im using UEFI... So will the bootloader/grub be installed on sda by default? even if install the system on sdb?

Comment: Yes, to sda. I have tried installing to sdb, installer even says installing to sdb, but it overwrites my main /EFI/ubuntu on sda. I copy to sdb as backup and restore my grub.cfg with correct UUID for main install, but have to use grub menu to boot second install on sdb. Supposed other distributions will let you install to sdb. UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu Use Something Else then to choose partitions.  Or you can totally disconnect sda/Windows and install to sdb drive.

Comment: I've never got an acceptance for my answer while 2 other people thought my answer was valuable...  Any problems with my answer???  **:-(**

Comment: No, the problem being I could not boot into Ubuntu as you can see in my question [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/747772/ubuntu-based-distros-not-booting-into-cd-or-flash-drive) so I had not tried it out immediately because of this . I tried your method with mint and it worked! I used the first method you gave me "Using BIOS/UEFI" Thanks.

Comment: Favour returned: upvoted your question: You're an 8 rep user already!  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You basically have two possibilities: to BIOS/UEFI or not to BIOS/UEFI. Both possibilities have their advantages/disadvantages.

**Using BIOS/UEFI**

*Advantages*

1. Windows doesn't even know that Ubuntu is there.
2. Ubuntu gets an entire HDD to itself
3. Easier to delete Windows once you've used a *professional* OS.  ;-)

*Disadvantages*

1. You have to remember to press the button!  ;-)

**No BIOS**

*Advantages*

1. Just one menu to rule them all...
2. No need to hit the [F12] or whatever key on boot

*Disadvantages*

1. grub2 (the Ubuntu boot loader) incorporates the Windows boot loader into its own menu and boots Windows if you choose to. *However*, if you ever do a Windows boot repair, grub2 will be gone (Microsoft wants its OS to work and doesn't care about the rest of the world especially Linux) and you'll have to do a grub2 repair afterwards.

Comment: so are you saying, i install to my HDD and install the bootloader on the HDD. Then i choose between the HDD and SSD from my Boot Menu to chose between windows and ubuntu, right?

Comment: **Correct!**  If this answer did help, just click the little grey ☑ at the left of this text right now turning it into beautiful green.

Answer (score 0):

You would choose something else:

At the partition table you will recognize your free space on /dev/sdb unallocated space.

Make a new partition on this as big as your ram size and choose SWAP.

Then make a new partition about 500MB and choose EFI

Finally make a partition with filesystem EXT4 and mountpoint should be /
filling the rest of your unallocated space.

Make sure it says install bootloader on /dev/sda at the bottom or if it asks where

Comment: How can i set the location of the bootloader... after installing the system, i enter terminal and install efibootmgr, but how can I set its location to go onto sda rather than sdb?

Comment: Follow this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Its worth mentioning that you may be left with more boot selections than you actually need after completing this guide. You can download a program named grub-customizer and remove them later (Be sure to know which)